# Files with cyrillic letters in name public storage could not be retrieved in Laravel

Tags: php, apache, laravel-5.5

I'm getting Object not found error if file contains Cyrillic letters in it's name.
I'm using standard configuration with public storage and symbolic link to public directory and retrieving url to file using following code:

```
$url = Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::disk(config('filesystems.default'))
           ->url($file->getDiskPath());
```

Thank you for your help, in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I come up to some solution which fits my needs. Hope it will help someone who face it in future:

First of all I added support of slug for my item. Luckily I was already using [Spartie/laravel-tags](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-tags) package and it was as easy as add `HasSlug` trait to my model.

Then I wrote function which gave me url like:

```
baseUrl + '/get-item/' + item.slug.en + '/' + item.item_media.id
```

After then I created controller to catch `GET` request to that URL:

```
public function getItem($slug, $mediaId)
{
    $media = Media::find($mediaId);

    if($media !== null){
        $fileName = $media->filename;
        $filePath = $media->directory;
        $fileExt  = $media->extension;
        $fileMime = $media->mime_type;

    $path = Storage::disk(config('filesystems.default'))->path($filePath . '/'. $fileName . '.' . $fileExt);

    if(!File::exists($path)) abort(404);

    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type: ' . $fileMime,
    );

    return response()->download($path, $fileName, $headers);
    }
}
```

Of course `$slug` parameter is redundant in controller definition, but having this string in URL is very useful for SEO purposes.

### Update

Problem was not in Russian (or Cyrillic in route). In fact Larave does handle it correctly in route. The actual issue wasn in encoded special characters as per ([laravel. Replace %20 in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33956708/laravel-replace-20-in-url/33956792)) and following [link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/route-how-to-pass-url-as-a-parameter) gave me a hint to resolve in in very elegant way:

I rewrited url to following:

```
baseUrl + '/download?file=' + directory + filename + '.' + extension
```

after that my controller method changed as following:

```
public function getItem(Request $request)
{
    $media = null;

    if($request->has('file')) {
        $name = $request->get('file');
        $media = Media::forPathOnDisk(config('filesystems.default'), $name)->first();
    }

    if($media !== null){
        $fileName = $media->filename;
        $filePath = $media->directory;
        $fileExt  = $media->extension;
        $fileMime = $media->mime_type;

    $path = Storage::disk(config('filesystems.default'))->path($filePath . '/'. $fileName . '.' . $fileExt);

    if(!File::exists($path)) abort(404);

    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type: ' . $fileMime,
    );

    return response()->download($path, $fileName, $headers);
    }
}
```